# Network Stream reloading in a loop (Nginx/RTMP Streaming Server)

Tags: streaming, codec, rtmp, engineering

As the generic title suggests, I do not know exactly how to explain my problem, neither do I know what could cause it. Hopefully this ends up to be the right place looking for help, as I do not find related issues and I am tired  of troubleshooting the unknown after many hours now. So I hope for hints now that point me to the right direction.

**What I am trying to achieve** is to build a working streaming server for video broadcasting.

**What is working so far:**

I set up a hls streaming server with nginx. Pushing the data via RTMP works fine (meaning: data gets created on the server). I can navigate to the stream location in the browser and download the .m3u8 playlist there.
At this point I was very excited..

**What I'd expected:**

Connecting to the server in VLC plays back the stream.

**What actually happens:** *(or: the desperate attempt to explain the issue shortly)*

Opening the stream causes VLC to "constantly reload the stream", without actually loading/playing it. It seems like the data chunks get loaded, but before they get played, VLC reloads (or maybe loads the next chunk? Or does not load data at all?). Anyway, I never see a picture.

Because I cannot explain this very well I will leave instructions on how you may test the server yourself (at least for the next days, using OBS) and see what I mean (or report back a different behavior):

Feel free to open OBS and connect to:

- Server: [expired]
- Streamkey: debug

Start streaming
   and connect to the server at [expired]

I will gladly add missing configuration details if you request them in the comments. For now, I want to keep the question clean, and get an impression what you think may cause this behavior.. Codecs? Missing HTTP-Headers? Wrong configuration (chunksize/keyframe-rate/..)?

I highly appreciate your effort and will leave the streaming server open for demo purposes for a while. Please understand that for several reasons this server won't stay publicly accessible for a long time (a few days max).

-- Edit: For the technically interested, you can find the configuration files [in this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963809/nginx-streaming-server-serving-stream-that-causes-vlc-to-reload-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

using vlc -vv helped me to track down the issue. It was a missing character in one of the configuration files that caused vlc to not connect to the server.

Sorry for the noise.

(If you are interested in the resolution, check the stack-overflow post linked to in the question)